# Fullscreen camera preview in fragment

Tags: java, android

I've spent the last two days browsing SO to find answers, unsuccessfully.
I'm trying to reproduce a Snapchat-like app.

## What I have so far

- A `ViewPager` composed of 3 fragments.
- The middle fragment is supposed to display a camera preview, just like Snapchat, on the whole surface (not truly fullscreen but it should cover the entire UI between the status bar and the bottoms buttons)
- I'm able to display either:

  - The camera preview, with the correct ratio, but not covering its parent `View` (see picture 1 below)
  - The camera preview, covering its parent `View` but stretched (wrong ratio)

## What I need

- Avoid stretching the preview. Possibly, the preview would be cropped on both sides (left and right). See picture 2 below. I guess this is what Snapchat does. Or is there any other way?

## What I went through

- http://www.shakedos.com/2015/Aug/26/writing-an-android-portrait-camera-app.html
- [Make a SurfaceView larger than the screen (Fitting a camera preview to a SurfaceView larger than the display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348614/make-a-surfaceview-larger-than-the-screen-fitting-a-camera-preview-to-a-surface)
- [Android full screen camera - while keeping the camera selected ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29352406/android-full-screen-camera-while-keeping-the-camera-selected-ratio) : can't find the whole code

## Requirements

- I need to use the Camera API version 1, not version 2.
- Final photos must be taken in 4/3 format, not 16/9.
- Portrait is forced although pictures can be in landscape or portrait

Thank you

[image]